# Pandas: converting a None type array retrieved via API call from a list to a string (to enable use of Pivot Table)

Tags: python, pandas

I query an internal database, retrieve data, and create a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks *similar* to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'issue_key':['MED-187', 'MED-188', 'MED-190', 'MED-191'],
                    'creator': ['Smith, J', 'Williams, S', 'Wilson, T', 'Smith, J'],
                    'manufacturer': ['Mercedes', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                    'department': [['Sales'], ['Finance'], ['Operations'], ['Sales']],
                    'expense': [29181, 12809, 837, 2817]})

issue_key    creator        manufacturer      department        expense
MED-187      Smith, J       Mercedes          [Sales]           29181
MED-188      Williams, S    Audi              [Finance]         12809
MED-190      Wilson, T      Mercedes          [Operations]      837
MED-191      Smith, J       BMW               [Sales]           2817
```

I then attempt to pivot the data using the following:

```
import numpy as np
pivoted_data = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index='department', values='expense', aggfunc=np.mean)
```

But, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So, I convert the department column from what I ***think is a list*** (more on this later) to a string using the following:

```
df['new_department'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['department']]
```

which, as expected, results in:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'issue_key':['MED-187', 'MED-188', 'MED-190', 'MED-191'],
                    'creator': ['Smith, J', 'Williams, S', 'Wilson, T', 'Smith, J'],
                    'manufacturer': ['Mercedes', 'Audi', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                    'department': [['Sales'], ['Finance'], ['Operations'], ['Sales']],
                    'expense': [29181, 12809, 837, 2817],
                    'new_department': ['Sales', 'Finance', 'Operations', 'Sales']
                  })

issue_key    creator        manufacturer      department        expense     new_department
MED-187      Smith, J       Mercedes          [Sales]           29181       Sales
MED-188      Williams, S    Audi              [Finance]         12809       Finance
MED-190      Wilson, T      Mercedes          [Operations]      837         Operations
MED-191      Smith, J       BMW               [Sales]           2817        Sales
```

And, now I'm able to successfully pivot the data.

**However**, on the production data, I get the following error:

```
df['new_department'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['department']]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Investigating how the data is returned from the API, I called the following:

```
`df['activity'].unique()`
```

which results in:

```
array(["[<JIRA CustomFieldOption:  value='Sales', id='174'>]",
       "[<JIRA CustomFieldOption:  value='Finance', id='179'>]",
       "[<JIRA CustomFieldOption:  value='Operations', id='102'>]",
       'None'], dtype=object)
```

What comes back from the API is showing `None`, so the error message makes complete sense.

Any idea how to overcome this?  Is it possible to *convert* the `None` type in some way in order to iterate through the list?  Or, perhaps directly access the values in the array?

I've been investigating this for a few hours and am unable to resolve.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is a rogue `None` value in the "department" column then you can use a conditional statement inside the list comprehension to deal with it:

```
df['new_department'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) if l is not None else 'NA' for l in df['department']]
```

or more generally:

```
unwanted_values = [None,np.NaN]
df['new_department'] = ['NA' if l in unwanted_values else ','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['department']]
```